# What happens to Feign Client if RestTemplate is depricated in future

Tags: microservices, resttemplate, feign

We are about to start a new microservice based application and we are going to use Spring boot for this. Feign client is really convenient tool to use. But I recently came to know that Rest-Template is going to be deprecated and will be replaced by WebClient, and Feign Client internally uses Rest-Template. My question is what should be our action in this case.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, Spring Cloud OpenFeign does not use RestTemplate under the hood.

For example, you can also configure the use of [OkHttpClient or ApacheHttpClient](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-openfeign/3.0.0.M1/reference/html/#spring-cloud-feign-overriding-defaults) instead of the default one in order to support HTTP/2.

In response to your question, you can use the Spring Cloud OpenFeign independently of RestTemplate and WebClient.

Comment: I recommend to have a look at https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-openfeign/issues/824